# Centroid from Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, centroid

I have a discrete fourier transform from an black and white image and would like to have a rough estimation of the centroid of an white shape in it.

As far as I can tell from http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/fourier_analysis.pdf I should be able to look at the first descriptor and it will map to x and y coordinates.

My own experiments with OpenCV:s dft have failed to produce any results that supports this. Is there more information regarding this property that I could read up on?

Comment: I doubt if many people here know what OpenCV:s dft is. Can you give more details about your experiments?

Comment: @Ninda I'm basically doing http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html and looking at the values in complexI. But I'm more interested in if it should work at all.

Comment: I presume you downloaded the code, compiled it but the program doesn't work/does nothing/gives an error code/gives unexpected results/gives a result but you don't know how to interpret it. Should I guess?

Comment: @Ninda I'm not so interested in the implementation. I'm more interested if the property is correct. A fourier transform on an black and white image will result in the first descriptors representing the x and y coordinates of a centroid (roughly) and where to learn more about this property.

Comment: First of all, concerning the first paper you site the formulas (8) and (9) on page 12 are wrong since e.g. for (8) $k$ is missing in the exponent of the RHS (and the same for (9) for $u$). Correct formulas are (6) and (7) on page 9. The formula on the web page you cite are correct but misleading since the symbol $i$ is used twice, once as index and once as the imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$. I don't know if you are familiar with euler's formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula, but if you do then it is not diffucult to see that the second component is circular.

Comment: I will need a little bit of time, OK?

Comment: @Nimda Sure. Take the time you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the main concept behind Fourrier analysis is that "suitable" functions can be reconstructed by standard building block functions. First, in 1 dimension, one took the functions $1, \cos(t),\sin(t),\cos(2t),\sin(2t),\ldots$. The reconstruction of the function then took the form $f(t)=a_0+a_1\cos(t)+b_1\sin(t)+a_2\cos(2t)+b_2\sin(2t)+\ldots$. These functions posess the remarkable property that they are othogonal in the sense that $\int\sin(nt)sin(mt)\mathrm{d}t$ is only $\neq 0$ if $m=n$. (It is not unnatural that these functions also represent the modes of vibrations of a thin metal rod). It is just this property of orthogonality that permits us to filter out how much of a building block function should be used, hence the formulas for the calculation of the coefficients. For more information look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).The use of Euler's formula permits us to use the functions $1,e^{\iota t},e^{\iota 2t}e^{\iota 3t},\ldots$ instead. The application of Fourrier analysis in the article you mention is not the classical Fourrier analysis on 2D images, it is still a 1 dimensional application (it took me a while to see through that one). It is related to images in the sense that not all the pixels of the image are analysed but only a finite sequence of points $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_N$ that describe the contour of an object. Since points in a plane can be considered complex numbers classical Fourrier analysis can be used. The first term in the series is a constant point that equals the sum of the vectors of the contour, so it is the "center of gravitiy" or "centroid" of the object. The following term is of the form $a_1e^{\iota t}$ which is indeed a circle. This can be seen in this [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20%28cos%28x%29%2C%20sin%28x%29%29). This circle around the object is the one that best suits the points. Intuitively one can imagine the radius of this circle as the mean disctance. It is interesting to see what adding another term to the series does in this [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%201%2F2%28cos%28x%29%2C%20sin%28x%29%29%2B%20%28cos%282x%29%2C%20sin%282x%29%29). If you have more questions please don't hesitate.